# Tensor Transformation Proof

Tags: tensors, index-notation

I am working through a Continuum Mechanics book for self study and came across the following question:

> Let ${e_i}$ and ${e_i'}$ be two rectangular Cartesian base vectors.
>   Show that if $e_i'=Q_{mi}e_m$ then $e_i = Q_{im}e_m'$.

I understand $Q$ to be an orthogonal tensor. Now the proof in the book goes as follows:

> $e_i'=Q_{im}e_m \rightarrow e_i' \cdot e_j = Q_{mi}e_m \cdot e_j = Q_{mi} \delta_{mj} = Q_{ji} \rightarrow e_j = Q_{jm}e_m'$

Now my question is, how does that last implication follow above (i.e. how did we suddenly get $e_j = Q_{jm}e_m'$)?

If someone could explain that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $\{e_i'\}$ vectors form an orthogonal basis, we can write:
$$e_j = (e_j\cdot e_i')e_i' = Q_{ji}e_i'$$
as we know that $Q_{ji} = e_j\cdot e_i'$.